Uninstalling asahi linux partitions
i followed the steps in a video but its not working, heres how it looks
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:             Apple_APFS_ISC Container disk1         524.3 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk4         171.6 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         2.5 GB     disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS drive                   524.3 MB   disk0s4
   5:                  Apple_HFS drive                   939.5 MB   disk0s5
   6:                  Apple_HFS drive                   69.3 GB    disk0s6
                    (free space)                         134.7 MB   -
   7:        Apple_APFS_Recovery Container disk3         5.4 GB     disk0s7

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.5 GB     disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume asahi_linux - Data      1.8 MB     disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume asahi_linux             1.1 MB     disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 191.4 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                805.4 MB   disk2s4

/dev/disk4 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +171.6 GB   disk4
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     148.9 GB   disk4s1
   2:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            10.3 GB    disk4s3
   3:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 10.3 GB    disk4s3s1
   4:                APFS Volume Preboot                 6.2 GB     disk4s4
   5:                APFS Volume Recovery                937.3 MB   disk4s5
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      2.7 GB     disk4s6

/dev/disk5 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk5
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk5s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk6         1000.0 GB  disk5s2

/dev/disk6 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1000.0 GB  disk6
                                 Physical Store disk5s2
   1:                APFS Volume Backup Plus             27.3 GB    disk6s2
   2:                APFS Volume Time Machine            492.3 GB   disk6s3


What video? What were the steps? Don't just link the video, but list the steps you took, paste the commands into your question.
